# Azure Bot Channel Registration for IIS hosted Microsoft Bot Framework sdk chat bot not working

Tags: c#, azure, iis, cors, botframework

I have created a chat bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework sdk that is working when tested on localhost with the Bot Framework Emulator along with the Microsoft App Id and Secret. I then deployed the bot on a publicly accessible IIS web server with the proper SSL certificate and when navigating to its link the proper "Your bot is ready!" page appears showing that it is up and running.

I then created a Bot Channels Registration on Azure with the messaging endpoint to my bot hosted on my IIS web server. However, when I try the "Test in Web Chat" the bot shows nothing and presents no error in the user interface. However looking at the browser's dev tools console, there are a couple of errors indicating that my bots URL is being blocked from the azure portal by CORS policy as shown below. Has anyone encountered this scenario and/or have possible solutions to this? Thank you!

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://MyBotUrl/api/messages/' from origin 'https://portal.azure.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://MyBotUrl/api/messages/' from origin 'https://portal.azure.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured CORS within IIS? If not, you'll need to. Allow the origin `https://portal.azure.com`. Is this a .NET Framework or .NET Core bot (or other)?

Unsure if it's needed, but there is an [IIS CORS module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is a .NET Core bot that targets .NET Core 2.1. I have added the custom header Access-Control-Allow-Origin with value "https://portal.azure.com" to the IIS web config and set the .Net Core middleware CORS policy in the startup.cs file of the bot itself. I also installed the IIS CORS module onto the webserver and did a iisreset but the behavior is still the same. I'm actually wondering if my bot channel registration resource on the azure side is what has the CORS issue, but I do not see any place to configure CORS in the Bot Channel Registration resource?

Comment: So, with all the above done, you don't see those headers in the browser's dev tools network request? If not, then it's still something on server side (either in IIS or .net core. not sure which).

Comment: Agreed, I added X-Custom-Header, x-ms-client-session-id, x-ms-client-request-id, x-ms-effective-locale to Access-Control-Allow-Headers. I set Access-Control-Allow-Methods of GET, POST and Access-Control-Allow-Origin portal.azure.com. Now i'm just receiving an error saying that the Origin header has multiple urls both being the portal.azure.com. I'm trying more things, hopefully i'm getting close.

Comment: It looks like now i'm receiving a status 400 error "Upgrade to WebSocket is required." while trying the web chat test.